# htaccess rewrite subdirectoy to file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with rewriting urls to my files. What I am trying to do is making my little shop system a bit more SEO friendly. My problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. I have no idea what I should do or what I am doing wrong.

My **UPDATED** `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^produkte/?(.*)$ products.php$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^produkt/?(.*)$ product.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(css|js|img|fonts)/(.*)?$ /shop/$2/$3 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

For example the `/shop/products` link is not working but `/shop/products/` is.

And for some reason if I want to open the link `/shop/products?cat=besteck` its redirecting me to: `localhost/D:/xampp/htdocs/shop/products.php?cat=besteck` but If I capitalize the `b` it's working fine..

I have no Idea what to do, please help me! (And dont just give a working code snippet explain why mine fails and yours works)

#### EDIT:

Just to clear things up I want `/products`, `/products/` and `/products?some_get_query` to redirect to my `products.php` file. `/product/some_seo_url` should be redirected to `product.php?url=some_seo_url`. I tried adding a question mark after the forward slash in my `RewriteRule` and I also tried putting the `^products` rule above the `^product` rule. Nothing worked yet.

### EDIT 2:

I updated my `.htaccess` code above and now nearly everything works. The only thing that still doesn't work is when I open `/shop/products/?cat=fish` or `/shop/product/some_product`, my resources aren't loading!

Comment: *For example the /shop/products link is not working but /shop/products/* ... you need to add a `?` : `RewriteRule ^product/? ...` to ensure it matches the trailing slash 0 or 1 times.

Comment: If I do that, it redirects me to: `localhost/D:/xampp/htdocs/shop/products.php`. And dont you mean `^products/?` consider the `s`.

Comment: *And dont you mean ^products/? consider the s* ... same on both of those rewrites, if you want the trailing slash to be optional it should be followed by a `?` whether it's the `product` rewrite or `products`

Comment: I hope you realise that when you edit your `.htaccess` you need to [manually] clear your browser history for that site, so that the site redownloads the newer htaccess file, otherwise the browser will just use the cached (old) copy and you will not see your updates take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /shop/404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products/?(.*)$ products.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/?(.*)$ product.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(css|js|img|fonts)/(.*)?$ /shop/$2/$3 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

First off your `product` rule also matches `products` so a rewrite like:

*products/cat/fish* becomes *product.php?url=s/cat/fish*

Which is not what you want, the easiest way to avoid that is to reverse the order so that the **products** rewrite comes before the **product** one but I've also added the **Last** flag (`[L]`) to be on the safe side; besides, once it's got the match you want it's better for it to stop looking.

To prevent recursive rewrite loops you need to specify that the rewrite only occurs when the redirect is **not** an existing file or directory (otherwise your *product* rewrite matches *product.php* and it loops - forever). That's what those `RewriteCond` lines signify.

Other than that it seems OK.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I still end up with the same redirect to url that includes whole server directory stuff..

Comment: There's got to be something else going on there... what you've got, with a little jiggering around, actually works. You should never get the DOCROOT in the address bar ... though I'm not sure that *is* the DOCROOT since `localhost/D:/xampp/htdocs/shop/products.php` just looks wrong - it looks like you're running on a Windows box ... but not?

Comment: Good explanation. I think the OPs problem comes from also not clearing their browser history after making `htacess` updates.

Comment: @Martin that's quite possible - incidentally I've found Chrome/Opera will tend to fetch the updated .htaccess file far more readily than Firefox.

Comment: I cleared my cache and tried again with a different but still not working result. Now `/shop/products` works with a slash at the end it doesnt. Also `/shop/product/some_url` is rewritten to my `products.php` file instead of `product.php` and the get query isnt rewritten from `/shop/products?cat=fish` to `products.php?cat=fish` instead its just `products.php`

Comment: Yes, I've found firefox somewhat lacking in that respect re: cached access files.

Comment: @Nicolas it's worth noting that the`?` character will make optional the character that comes immediately **before** it. This should help you decipher htaccess rules.

Comment: I updated my `htaccess` file. Still the get query isnt redirected to my php file. And whenever I add the forward slash to the end of `/shop/products` none of my css, js or img files are loaded. I get the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Comment: So I fixed the Problem with the GET parameter thing. I removed the second `?` from `RewriteRule ^products/?(.*)$ products.php?$1 [L]`

Comment: @CD001 I updated my question with your code and my little fix. Just a short little question can I add the `NC` flag behind the `L` to make the url case insensitive?

Comment: @Nicolas Yup, I generally just plonk in `[NC,L,QSA]` just in case I want to randomly append a querystring :) I didn't really look too closely at the CSS/JS rewrites; you can probably drop that rule completely and just reference them relative to the docroot in the HTML code (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/shop/css/styles.css" />`)

Comment: @CD001 thanks alot. I accepted your answer. Everything works fine now!